# Showing half of the prev and next images in owl carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

I have implemented owl carousel in my application. I need to show half of prev and next images on the modal gallery of main image.

The modal gallery opens when you click on the main bigger image of the page. I tried to set stagePadding property, but it didnt work out.

Can I achieve the same without stagePadding property.
I have implemented thumbnails and other parts. You can view the implemented fuctionality here.

https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/6836-Xana-Way_Carlsbad_CA_92009_M29922-47778

```
galleryId.owlCarousel({
           items: 1,
           loop: true,
           margin: 5,
           startPosition: 1,
           animateOut: 'fadeOut',
           navSpeed: 100,
           lazyLoad: true,
           dots: false,
           nav: true,
           stagePadding: 100,
});
```

Comment: did you try `center: true`?

Comment: @bigless Yes i tried with that. But it didnt work.Is it that something I need to also tweak the CSS. Did you get a chance to inspect it?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and my problem was solved with center:false.

```
 $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            center:false,
            nav: true,
            dots: false,
            loop: true,
            autoHeight: true,
            autoWidth:false,
            stagePadding: 10,
            margin: 30
        });
```